# Rails 3.1 + Paperclip + jQuery fileupload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload, paperclip

I've been looking for a way to set up Ruby on Rails 3.1 with [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) and [jQuery fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki). Looking at a tutorial at [jQuery fileupload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V5) page I got the system set up but I can't find a way to make paperclip process the uploaded file.

Here's what I have (in short):

```
# model
has_attached_file :photo ...

# view
= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  f.file_field :photo, :multiple => true
  f.submit

# controller
def create
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  if @user.save
    render :json => [...]
end
```

If I inspect submitted data I get all user properties in params[:user] and params[:user][:photo] which is ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile. When @user.save is called the image doesn't get processed or saved.

A clue, tutorial or a solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: Mass-assignment protection on `User` requiring the addition of `photo` to `attr_accessible`?

Comment: Thanks @DouglasFShearer I'll have a look and report back. If I remember correctly I've already tried with `attr_accessible :photo`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After struggling with this problem for a while I discovered the problem appeared when `:multipart => true` is added to the `f.file_field` since the form field name changes from `user[photo]` to `user[photo][]`.

**Using separate page to attach photos**

I want to have a separate page for uploading multiple files to a record (and another one for editing User's properties). This looks to me as a temporary solution but it works. Instead of `f.form_field :photo, :multipart => true` I used `form_field_tag 'user[photo]', :multiple => true` in the view.

My code looks like this:

```
## app/model/user.rb
has_attached_file :photo

def to_fileupload_json
  {
    "name" => photo_file_name,
    "size" => photo_file_size,
    ...
  }
end

## app/views/photos/new.html.haml
= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  #fileupload
    = file_field_tag 'user[photo]', :multiple => true
    = f.submit

= javascript_include_tag "jquery.fileupload.js"
# require all other JS files needed for the plugin (jQuery, jQuery UI, ...)
= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.fileupload-ui.css"
= render :partial => "jquery_file_templates" # partial with jQuery templates for responses 

:javascript
  $(function () {
      uploader = $('#fileupload').fileupload()
  }


## app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def create
  @user = User.create params[:user]
end
```

If anyone else knows a better way (the right way) of doing this, please let us know!

**Using fields_for**

Depending on the structure of your app you might consider using `fields_for`.

In this case you'll have to:

- add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos` to your (User) model
- add a method `photos_attribues=(attributes)` to your (User) model and handle record creation there
- build record for photos `3.times { @user.photos.build }` in User's new method

Example:

```
def photos_attribues=(attributes)
  attributes.each do |key, value|
    photo = Photo.create :photo => value, ...
  end
end
```

*Disclaimer: The code above was simplified/rewritten to make it easier to understand. I might've made mistakes while erasing unneeded stuff. And again - I'm not really sure this is the right way of solving this problem. Suggestions and improvements are more than welcome!*

Comment: I am having trouble recreating your examples here. I am able to see the plugin and select multiple files, but NULL is being inserted. If I just have one file selected without using the file_field_tag then it works just fine but only for one file.

Comment: Also, the jquery is not displaying the files and the progress bars

Comment: @kobaltz check form field names and request headers and make sure they match (what rails is sending and what jquery fileupload is looking for). I had no problems with plugin displaying files along with file sizes and thumbnails. Haven't played with progress bar though.

Comment: Is there a reasonable way to allow any number of files to be uploaded, not just 3?

Comment: Pretty sure the appended array on the user[photo][] is caused by :multiple => true not :multipart => true.  Can anyone verify?

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly set the name on the `file_field`:

```
f.file_field :photo, multiple: true, name: 'user[photo]'
```

Rails will generate `user[photo]` instead of `user[photo][]`.