# ruby on rails:multiple upload and view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am currently using paperclip to upload a single photo. When the user goes to the show view, it shows the photo and the info related to it. Now I want to update it to accept multiple photos so that all of the photos are shown on the show view. What do I need to use? (JavaScript and update paper-clip to take multiple uploads?) Or is there something else?

I have read http://sleekd.com/general/adding-multiple-images-to-a-rails-model-with-paperclip/

Comment: You say you have read that article. Did you *try* to implement their solution?

Comment: no. because i want an advice first.if this article will do what i want and if not what options i have

Comment: You should probably implement their solution in a new rails app then play around with it and see if you can get it to do what you want. If you can't then at the very minimum you know what doesn't work and can ask for more specific help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle multi file upload I suggest you use this jquery library

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Its very in depth and great for multi-file upload.

Also, this good example as to how to implement with paperclip.

[Rails 3.1 + Paperclip + jQuery fileupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883118/rails-3-1-paperclip-jquery-fileupload)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Photo class which will save photos. Like this

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :your_class_having_photos

  #paperclip methods and validations ....
end
```

In your upload view:

```
<%=file_field "'photos'[]"%>
<%=file_field "'photos'[]"%>
<%=file_field "'photos'[]"%>

...
```

do it as many as you want by JS or hardcoding whatever. Then after submit, there will be a parameter called params[:photos] containing an array of multiple photos in it. Then you can do

```
params[:photos].each do |p|
   photo = @your_class_object.photos.build(p)
   photo.save
end
```

in your controller, or maybe in more nicer codes you want.